# Android sdk 3.0: How to set applicationId when using UiLifecycleHelper.java?

Tags: android, facebook, session

I recently migrated from FB for Android 2.0 to 3.0.

Instead of using

`<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>`

in my AndroidManifest.xml, I wanted to programmatically set my application Id to a session.

I know that I can use Session.Builder.setApplicationId() upon the creation of a session object.
However, when I use **UiLifecycleHelper.java**, it creates a session without using session.Builder. It only uses its constructor (session = new Session(activity)).
It seems like it assumes that I already defined a meta-data for app id in my manifest file.
However, I want UiLifecycleHelper.java to create a session by using Session.Builder and programmatically applying my application Id in its onCreate().

How can I do it? I google it but haven't found any solution yet.
Is it a common practice to use meta data to set FB application Id in the manifest file? I really don't want to reveal my app Id by putting it in an xml file. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Your Application ID is NOT considered a secret (just like how a person's profile ID is not a secret).

But if you really don't want to use the xml method, you can copy or subclass UiLifecycleHelper and change the appropriate method to use your own way of creating a Session.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set it in the code, you can change the method **`getMetadataApplicationId()`** from **Utility.Java** and add your code to set the application id to whatever you like.

Comment: how ? please explain that.